# Magical Record NSFetchedResultsController NSManagedObject Changes Save Not Working

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have Used NSFetchedResultController to load data into UITableView. Am Using MagicalRecord for coredata operations.

I have created **NSFetchedResultsController in default context**, and on **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** i have used it like below

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
UserEntity * user = [userFetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

// do some changes to user Object 
}
```

later upon save button click action i have tried to save like below

```
[[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext] saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    DLog(@" isSaved : %d ",success);
}];
```

but changes are not saved,

```
2014-09-22 17:12:50.752 _block_invoke [Line 210] has Changed 1
2014-09-22 17:12:50.752 MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x7fca7214e7d0) → Saving <NSManagedObjectContext (0x7fca7214e7d0): *** DEFAULT ***> on *** MAIN THREAD ***

2014-09-22 17:12:50.753 MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x7fca7214e7d0) → Save Parents? 1

2014-09-22 17:12:50.753 MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x7fca7214e7d0) → Save Synchronously? 0

2014-09-22 17:12:50.759 MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x7fca7214c430) NO CHANGES IN ** BACKGROUND SAVING (ROOT) ** CONTEXT - NOT SAVING

2014-09-22 17:12:50.759 _block_invoke_2 [Line 213]  isSaved : 0
```

Clearly NSManagedObject has Changes , but log says No Changes , can anyone explain this one ?

**UPDATE:**

I could see the changed object in defaultContext UpdatedObjects list, not still saving not working

```
DLog(@" updated Objects %@ ",  [[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext] updatedObjects]);

 updated Objects {(
<UserEntity: 0x1780cd4a0> (entity: UserEntity; id: 0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://1E0810DA-1A23-4337-B279-3957BE4D207F/UserEntity/p1> ; data: {
   // entity data removed 
})
)} 

NO CHANGES IN ** BACKGROUND SAVING (ROOT) ** CONTEXT - NOT SAVING
```

any suggestion would be very helpful

**UPDATE 2:**

below is how i create NSFetchedResultsController

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController*) userFetchedResultsController {
@autoreleasepool {
    if(userFetchedResultsController == nil){

        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [UserEntity requestAllSortedBy:@"userName" ascending:YES];
        [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:10];

        NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext] sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

        userFetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
        userFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    }
    return userFetchedResultsController;
}
}
```

Comment: Please insert the code where you are making changes. Then after that you can log [context updatedObjects] to see which objects have updates:)

Comment: Hi daniel, i could see the the changed UserEntity Object in updatedObjects 
but when i try to save it says as before no changes

 NO CHANGES IN ** BACKGROUND SAVING (ROOT) ** CONTEXT - NOT SAVING

Comment: In order to get a better understanding I need to see which NSManagedObjectContexts you are using for the following: Setting up the fetched results controller and updating the object.

Comment: i have used defaultContext created by magical Record, check Update 2 to see how am creating NSFetchedResultsController

Comment: For updating i dint use any context instead i would simply get the data from nsfetchedresultscontroller and update the changes.

Comment: perhaps there is a validation error in the context. Try and call save:&error and print out if there is any errors?

Comment: i did, the error object id null.

Comment: So if you try and delete the object from the context or add a new object from the context does that work? Trying to see if its updates that are failing or any changes at all.

Comment: ya create and delete is working fine with context, but update its not at all working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61740/discussion-between-daniel-galasko-and-ramesh).

Comment: Hi Daniel, i feel terrible, it was an Boolean Object issue, which cause the context not to update (logical bug). thank you so much for your time. its works fine now.

Comment: no worries, its how we learn. Just make sure to post your answer as well:)

Answer (score -1):

It was actually an logical bug in my side which reset the NSManagedObject values resulting in no changes in context.

Updateing Works fine now.